# Please unleash Trogdor on the homework tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

In accordance with the [preliminary discussion on the homework tag](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313/what-should-the-homework-tag-mean) and the [homework policy adopted by a community poll](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/468/homework-policy), please burninate (remove and blackist) the [homework](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag.

[image: Trogdor!]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm... Looks like a dragon ate your [homework](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework)

[image: a dragon...man]

Please care for [the widows and orphans](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

Comment: We take care of our own; they are properly prepped when they are born.

Comment: Seems that you can't keep a bad tag down. Can we have it blacklisted again please?

Comment: That is now Done, @Gilles