# Homework policy

Tags: discussion, faq, policy, homework

The [accepted answer](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/470) on this question is our homework policy, adopted by a community poll.

The poll rules and outcome are retained below for historical purposes.

---

#### Rules

Below, you will find three proposed policies regarding homework
questions. Please upvote the one(s) you agree with and downvote the
one(s) you disagree with (or don't vote if you're ambivalent or
indifferent).

The voting period runs for 1 week, until Thursday, July 5, 2012 at 23:59:59
GMT. After that:

- If the dominant option has a score of at least 5 and at least 2
  more than the next contender, that policy will be adopted.
- Otherwise, the moderators will meet and decide on a provisional
  policy, which will last until meta participation is sufficient to
  achieve a consensual improvement.

#### Background

- [Will homework questions be allowed?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/will-homework-questions-be-allowed)
  → Homework questions are allowed, but we might want to have a policy
  of giving hints or requiring effort.
- [Homework tag discussion](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17/homework-tag-discussion)
  → we should probably have some kind of policy; it is unclear whether
  to mark homework questions with a [homework](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag, and there is
  some disagreement as to what that tag might mean.
- [Just-a-hint tag](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177/just-a-hint-tag) → a
  proposal for a [just-a-hint](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/just-a-hint) tag got neither any significant
  traction nor any significant opposition.
- [What should the homework tag mean?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313/what-should-the-homework-tag-mean)
  → There is a strong voice against having a [homework](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag, and no
  one has defended the tag *and* explained what it should mean.
- [Towards a homework policy](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/460/towards-a-homework-policy)
  → led to three proposals that are offered here.

#### Results

- Raphael's proposal: 10 (+14/-4)
- David Lewis's proposal: 7 (+10/-3)
- Patrick87's/Gilles's proposal: 2 (+4/-2)

Since Raphael's proposal has a score of at least 5, and has at least 2 more votes than the next runner-up, this proposal is adopted, effective immediately.

Comment: Moderator notice: this thread represents the poll that led to the present policy and has been archived. If you wish to reopen the subject, open a new meta thread and expose why you wish the policy to change.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Policy

We do not try to decide which questions are homework, and we don't use
a special tag. Users that want to receive hints rather than full
answers should say so, and answerers should honor such requests (by
not posting details or hiding them in spoiler tags). Other than that,
the usual quality control applies.

### Guideline

All users should be aware that askers might use cs.SE to cheat and are
asked to act responsibly (e.g. by not answering, answering after a
delay or providing only hints) if they suspect a question is a mere
restatement of a homework exercise without own effort.

### Rationale

We have no way of identifying homework questions reliably and in
general (with notable exceptions). Therefore, we have to take what
users post at face value. However, from a teaching point-of-view, it
is often more helpful to a student to be *led to* an answer instead of
*told* the answer. That is why we should work with helpful hints
rather than detailed answers where appropriate.

[homework](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) has no use given such a policy.

On the other hand, we want to prevent students from exploiting cs.SE
to do their homework (i.e. cheat the system and themselves), as that
would not help them *and* might gain the site a bad reputation among
teachers. Most homework-dump-style questions should be dealt with by
usual quality-control, but that response might come with a delay or,
in special cases, never. In these cases, it is up to the users to
decide how to act.

### Source

[Raphael's proposal](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/460/towards-a-homework-policy/461#461)

Answer (score 7):

*(Note: if adopted, references to mathematics and Math.SE shall be
adapted to computer science and CS.SE.)*

### Policy

#### Can I ask a homework question here?

There are actually two factors involved here, one is on your end, and
one over here on this website.

As a general rule, we do not discourage any specific category of
questions, as long as it is mathematical. But please **do** make an
effort to search through the list of previously asked questions. In
our experience homework questions are usually not very imaginative,
and tend to fall in one of the [abstract categories of commonly asked
questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1756/). We
**will** close duplicate questions, especially if they are of homework
type.

On the other hand, whether your learning institution (middle school,
high school, college, etc.) and your teacher or professor allows you
to consult other people, or to post the exact question on the
internet, is something that is usually addressed by your institution's
honor code or rules and regulations, and any specific class policies.
You should ask your teacher whether asking a homework question here is
appropriate before posting your question.

#### How do I ask a homework question on this website?

Please use the [homework
tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework). This
serves several purposes: the most important of which is to let the
answerer know to give an answer that more clearly explains the
underlying concepts. In other words, we believe in the "teach a man to
fish" philosophy.

Also, please put some work into formulating your question. Please **do
not** just copy and paste the exact question text from your homework
sheet. In particular, when you are asking for help, writing in
imperative mode ("Show that...", "Compute...", or "Prove or find a
counterexample: ...") is at the very least impolite: you are, after
all, [trying to ask a question, not give an
assignment](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). It
also turns many people off.

If you feel that it is somehow just so much more straightforward to
copy and paste, then it is generally good real world advice to both
**quote the question** (because you are copying after all) and **give
a reference** to the source (so that others can refer to the context
of the question).
You should also volunteer all relevant information (see next section).
It is a waste of everybody's time if someone has to ask for what you
should explicitly have given.

#### What information should I include in a question about homework?

The following are some things that may help your question get better
answers, or at least answer more tailored to your situation.

- *The context*. What kind of course it is, what textbook you use.
  It wouldn't help you if someone gives an answer using some
  sophisticated, high-powered machinery that you have never seen before.
  (An example would be asking for help about a step that is used to
  prove a big theorem in the textbook, and receiving an answer using
  said big theorem.)
- *All the definitions*. If you are asking about a question that is
  more advanced than basic college-level calculus, then you should
  consider including the definitions. A lot of homework questions are
  assigned to familiarize you with the definitions used in the course.
  For many objects in mathematics there are several equivalent
  definitions. What needs to be proven when starting from one set of
  definitions may actually be a trivial consequence in a different set
  of definitions and vice versa. It is important that you let us know
  what framework in which you work so our answers can properly address
  the question.
- *Show your work*. You should definitely include any partial work
  you have done. This will help bolster your claim that you are not just
  coming here asking other people to do your homework for you, and it
  will help the answerers to give more clinical responses. Showing your
  work will help us gauge where you are having problems: if it is a
  technical thing near the end, a short to the point answer will
  suffice; if it is some fundamental problem with understanding the
  subject, we will then write a longer, more detailed response. It will
  also prevent people from spending a lot of time going over ground that
  you have already covered or understand well already.

#### Why don't you provide a complete answer to my question?

We've had another
[discussion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/415) from
the point of view of the answerer, and you should see that for a more
complete discussion. To quote the accepted answer in that thread, we
feel that

> Providing an answer that doesn't help
>   a student learn is not in the
>   student's own best interest, and if a
>   solution complete enough to be copied
>   verbatim and handed in is given
>   immediately, it will encourage more
>   people to use the site as a free
>   homework service. In the spirit of
>   creating a lasting resource of
>   mathematical knowledge, you may come
>   back after a suitable amount of time
>   and edit your response to include a
>   more complete answer. Or even better,
>   the student can post his own correct
>   answer!

### Rationale

This is the current policy on our sister site [Mathematics Stack
Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

### Source

[Proposed by David
Lewis](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/460/towards-a-homework-policy/462#comment1365_460)
with the following endorsement:

> I vote for the Math Area policy.  As a former teacher, I am uncomfortable without at least a policy that encourages students to mark their questions as
>   homework and responders to answer such questions with hints rather
>   than fully worked out solutions.  I know there are many problems with
>   such a policy, but
>   I'd rather not just capitulate in the face of them and open things up
>   totally for homework cheating (for that's what it is).  At least if
>   there is a policy
>   in place, some if not most of the honest folks will do the right
>   thing. Without such a policy, honest folks are penalized.

Comment: I don't like the policy because of the neverending struggle marking homework causes, but there is some good general advice in there we might want to copy in any case.

Comment: I like this policy because it is the same for the sites I visit, and I like the consistency.

Comment: `Please use the homework tag. This serves several purposes: the most important of which is to let the answerer know to give an answer that more clearly explains the underlying concepts. In other words, we believe in the "teach a man to fish" philosophy.`  So unless there's a meta tag, poorly explained answers are acceptable?  If the user needs help with concepts in an answer it might even be a good idea to post another question about those concepts.

Comment: @MatthewRead: No. Users can state in the question text that they prefer hints and/or need details. Usually, the way the question if phrased also allows to estimate the asker's level. Even though, follow-up questions are a good tool.

Comment: For reference: [math.SE no longer uses the homework tag, by overwhelming community majority](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/16425/3330).

Answer (score 1):

### Policy

Homework questions are not treated differently.

### Rationale

This way homework questions do not get any special treatment, they are
subject to the usual quality control rules. We do not need to argue
over whether a question is homework or not, and we can get rid of the
meaningless [homework](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag. We may have guidelines advising how to
post a good homework question and how to answer homework questions,
but these will not be binding rules.

#### Source

[Patrick87's proposal](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/460/towards-a-homework-policy/462#462)
and [Gilles's proposal](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/460/towards-a-homework-policy/463#463)
(merged due to similarity)