# Why did this "check my result question" not get close votes?

Tags: discussion

For the question [Maximum Virtual Address Space](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18307/268) it currently has 65 views and no close votes.

I was expecting one or more close votes of the kind, "Here is my problem, here is my reasoning, here is my answer. Check my work."

To me it seems that sometimes we close these questions and at other times we leave them alone.

I know we decided:
1. Being a homework question is not a factor.
2. Expect the question to be practical.
3. Can have a practical answer.
4. Has not been asked before (i.e. duplicate question here or on another site).
5. The question points to a specific problem the OP has with the problem.
6. The OP has demonstrated the work they have preformed in trying to solve the specific problem so that the answer can teach the OP something. (No homework dumps of just the question and especially no scans of a homework problem as these show no effort by the OP that can be used to help the OP other than giving them the answer).
7. The question can have an answer that can help others learn. (A question that has a simple yes or no answer would not be beneficial.)

I also see that the OP gave a reasoning behind their answer which if not present would possibly get one or more down votes, one or more close votes, and possibly a comment requesting the OP to explain what they have tried or a recommendation on what to try.

I am mostly asking this so that I can be more consistent with close votes. I would prefer to help people here rather than close the question, but I realize that all of us having a consistent response is better than expressing individual views when in comes to closing questions.

Related meta discussions:
[What constitutes an appropriate check-my-proof question?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/647/268)
[What to do when the answer is already part of the question](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/597/268)
[Should we have a custom close reason for homework assignment dumps?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/775/268)
[Close votes that don't apply to the question](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/771/268)
[Should we downvote solution request?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/740/268)

So the question is: Should the referenced question have been closed, or what do I need to add to my close repertoire.

Comment: There were certain holidays that may have influenced page-visiting behaviour of some people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right.  Good call.  I agree that it should be closed.

Fortunately, it looks like Raphael took care of it for us.  (After seeing your meta post, I went to cast a close vote of the form you mentioned, but I see that Raphael beat me to it.)  Thanks, Raphael.

Comment: Actually, thanks Guy Coder because I would never have checked the question were it not for this post.